# How to allow boxshadow over iframe google map embed?

Tags: html, css, iframe, box-shadow

So I am having a bit of a issue that I just cannot figure out.  I have a website that has a div before and after a google map Embed (iframe).  The bottom portion of the map shows the shadow of the below div but whenever I negative z-index and position relative the shadow shows up but the functions no longer work on the map...  Is there a way to have the shadow show up and still have function of the map?

So in short if I have the shadow show up it stops all map functions from being unusable (drag / zoom / etc.).  The only issue is the top shadow as the bottom shows up with no issue.  If I remove the z-index: -10 from the map the functions come back but the shadow is gone...  Any tips?

**Code example:**

***HTML***

```css
#menu-divider {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000;
}

#map {
 position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 border: none;
}

footer {
  z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 height: 100px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-us">

<head>
 <title>example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="menu-divider">
</div>

<iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d11797.683090046503!2d-83.05766876093261!3d42.333551617017015!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x883b2d31a25efc0f%3A0x114c7a5b16dfbdd4!2sDowntown%2C+Detroit%2C+MI!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1534087083348" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I'm stupid and figured it out myself...  Had to add  position: relative and
    z-index: 10 to #menu-divider and wrap the map in a holder.

EDIT: Add height to match map to holder to remove white space at bottom...

***Working code:***

```css
#menu-divider {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000;
}

#map-holder {
 position: relative;
    height:300px;
}

#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 border: none;
}

footer {
  z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 height: 100px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-us">

<head>
 <title>example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="menu-divider">
</div>

<div id="map-holder"><iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d11797.683090046503!2d-83.05766876093261!3d42.333551617017015!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x883b2d31a25efc0f%3A0x114c7a5b16dfbdd4!2sDowntown%2C+Detroit%2C+MI!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1534087083348" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

<footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
#layout {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

#map {
  border: none;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d11797.683090046503!2d-83.05766876093261!3d42.333551617017015!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x883b2d31a25efc0f%3A0x114c7a5b16dfbdd4!2sDowntown%2C+Detroit%2C+MI!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1534087083348" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Better [DEMO](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/pZYobw) here

Comment: This example actually is not functional, check out the functions on the map in my Answer.  Cannot scroll zoom or anything....

Comment: Updated: I modified the CSS to do what you want and also fill the screen. The map was dynamic before to support the current viewport width/height/functionality. You are currently setting a fixed height to map container so it will always show the controls.

Comment: I need a fixed height for my site...  Thanks tho